# Searching by a coordinate using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, openlayers

I have a coordinate (longitude, latitude) which I get from my map (I'm using OSM with OpenLayers) so I get something like this lon: -46.502541777468984 lat: -23.474943422638063.

What I need? I need to know if there is some function in PostGIS that I can use to search on my database which will return the nearest result that I have in DB.

I know I can do this using a select, but it take too much time.

Comment: See my answer for a minor correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is just from one table then you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY geom <-> 'SRID=4326;POINT(-46.502541777468984 -23.474943422638063)'::geometry
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: @AdenirSouza use that method instead. see the update.

Comment: @EvanCarroll if you have a better answer feel free to add it. I'm happy with my query.

Comment: glad to, done. =)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the chosen method. It's relying on unstandardized text-to-point conversion and is otherwise subject to rounding errors. They won't be a problem because of the precision, they will be a problem because of equality-testing. `ST_MakePoint` is typed is and standardized OGC/SQL-MM 3: 8.1.3, 9.5.4.

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY geom <-> ST_MakePoint(-46.502541777468984,-23.474943422638063)::geography
LIMIT 1;
```

EKWT(with the SRID in the WKT) is a PostGIS thing, and if OGC or ISO standardizes it then that behavior may change.

In my example above, I'm using the `geography` type because it's probably what you want anyway and it defaults to srid 4326.

Comment: I've tested your method, but besides it worked when I tested directly on pgAdmin it did not work when I applied in my application. But thank you for your help!